# When I want to compile catkin_ws it give me this error

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-kinetic, build-package, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to compile catkin_ws folder after I unziped a simulation package from "the construct" web site. When I run the comand `catkin_make` I receive this error:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pid" with any of
  the following names:

    pidConfig.cmake
    pid-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pid" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "pid_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "pid" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  kobuki/simulation_ws/src/turtlebot/follow_line_tc_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'pid'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "pid" with any of
  the following names:

    pidConfig.cmake
    pid-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "pid" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "pid_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "pid" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  kobuki/simulation_ws/src/turtlebot/follow_line_tc_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ovidiu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I use kinetic ROS.

Can someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333671/when-i-want-to-compile-catkin_ws-it-give-me-this-error/) by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As with all ROS packages, you cannot just clone/unzip *just* that package and start building.

You need to make sure to have all dependencies installed, or compilation will fail.

Please refer to #q252478 for an example workflow.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-24**:
Thanks! I did the steps from the winner answer of the link you pointed. Now i can compile the folder but the packages don't appear in ROS packages list. What can i do?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-24**:
I'm not sure what "the ROS packages list" is.

Make sure to `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` after running `catkin_make`. Check whether packages can be found with `rospack find $pkg_name`. If that doesn't work, try running `rospack profile` and try `rospack find` again.

**Comment by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on 2019-09-24**:
That was the problem... `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` solved the problem